# Bootstrap Sign Form Example - "required" attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The "signin" example html form that comes with the Bootstrap examples has a "required" attribute for the 2 form fields on the sign in form:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
```

From what I can tell this doesn't actually make these fields mandatory - you can still submit the form in this example if both fields are empty.

Can anyone explain what the "required" attribute is for and how it works? I presume you would need to use another validation plugin/Javascript to actually make these fields mandatory before the form can be submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required attribute is a HTML5 form attribute which is used with input controls inside a form.
Using the required attribute will make sure on form submit that the required field is filled in otherwise a validation error will be shown by the browser.

You can try [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/pTEbA/258/) in various browsers and see the message when no input value is given.

FYI,
The required attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Safari. You don't need to use any special validation plugins for that. Its part of HTML5 new attributes and will automatically be fired by supported browsers when form is submitted.

```
<form action="">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks - I was using Safari which explains why I wasn't seeing any validation taking part.